# css element border include margin-top

Tags: css

I have a div tag that has a style set of at margin-top: 25px

Now when I try to add a border surrounding the div tag it does not include the margin-top.  Is it even possible?

I've been googling around and so far have found nothing.

Comment: Would you be that kind and include some code representing the problem? Right now we can give you nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `padding-top` instead. The border shows up between the margin box and the padding box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `padding-top` instead of margin and your markup/CSS should look something like this pen: http://codepen.io/gillytech/pen/yCAnE

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```